# Inconsistent xdebug behavior

Tags: drupal, netbeans, mamp, xdebug, virtualhost

I am running MAMP on OSX 10.8.2 with NetBeans. I installed xdebug for debugging Drupal sites locally. I have quite a few so I have vhosts set up.

I am encountering a weird inconsistency. On mysite.loc I drop a breakpoint into index.php, fire up the debugger, and it works fine. The breakpoint catches, I can run, step into, step over, etc.

On the same site, I drop a breakpoint into template.php (in my active theme). I threw a some debugging text into the function to make sure that the function that contains the breakpoint is being called. My debugging text appears, but the breakpoint never catches. Run and step buttons stay greyed out.

When I end the debug session I get no errors.

What is happening?

Comment: Are you using symlinks? What does the remote log say? (http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log)